# How can we install "port" for P12 key (Service Account) to access Analytics?

Tags: python, macos, google-analytics, pip, macports

```
Pip install port
```

or

```
sudo pip install port
```

or

```
pip3 install port
```

It downloads the packages but is not installing. It is used to install pyOpenSSL:

```
port install libffi
```

homebrew

```
brew install libffi
```

ubuntu

```
apt-get install libffi-dev
```

this will install pyOpenSSL along with these others:
 cryptography cffi six pycparser
 if you encounter the 'flat namespace' error while installing cryptography, see this blog post:
 http://chriskief.com/2014/03/25/installing-cryptography-via-pip-with-macports-or-homebrew/

```
pip install pyOpenSSL
```

Already updated lib and Ubuntu files.
1- `sudo apt-get update`
2- `sudo apt-get upgrade`
3- `pip3 install port`

after downloading the packages, it is showing:

ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /home/abdullah/anaconda3/bin/python -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-gszlcz5q/lxml/setup.py'"'"'; **file**='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-gszlcz5q/lxml/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /tmp/pip-record-cj49_w44/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile Check the logs for full command output.

```
import httplib2

from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from googleapiclient.http import HttpError
from oauth2client.client import SignedJwtAssertionCredentials

def get_metrics():

    # load the service account key
    # this key is managed here - https://console.developers.google.com/project
    filename = 'YOUR-KEY-FILE.p12'
    f = file(filename, 'rb')
    key = f.read()
    f.close()

    # create the credentials
    credentials = SignedJwtAssertionCredentials('SERVICE-ACCOUNT-EMAIL-ADDRESS@developer.gserviceaccount.com', key, scope='https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly')

    # authorize the http instance with these credentials
    http = httplib2.Http()
    http = credentials.authorize(http)

    # construct a resource object for interacting with an api
    service = build('analytics', 'v3', http=http)

    # build the query
    # your profile id can be found by heading to google analytics, selecting your profile, clicking the admin button, 
    # and then clicking view settings under the view column, the id is labelled 'View ID'
    # you can see the available metrics here:
    # https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets
    api_query = service.data().ga().get(
        ids='ga:YOUR_PROFILE_ID_NOT_UA',
        metrics='ga:users, ga:sessions, ga:avgSessionDuration, ga:pageviews, ga:pageviewsPerSession, ga:percentNewSessions, ga:bounceRate',
        start_date='2014-01-01',
        end_date='2015-01-01'
    )

    # default value
    metrics = None

    # run it
    try:
        result = api_query.execute()
        values = result['rows'][0]

        # covert the average session to minutes and seconds
        minutes, seconds = divmod(int(float(values[2])), 60)

        # the order below is the same as the order the metrics were listed above
        metrics = {
            'users': values[0],
            'sessions': values[1],
            'avg_session': '%d:%02d' % (minutes, seconds),
            'pageviews': values[3],
            'pages_session': '%.2f' % float(values[4]),
            'new_sessions': '%.2f' % float(values[5]) + '%',
            'returning_sessions': '%.2f' % (100 - float(values[5])) + '%',
            'bounce_rate': '%.2f' % float(values[6]) + '%'
        }

    # handle errors in constructing a query
    except TypeError, error:
        print ('There was an error in constructing your query : %s' % error)

    # handle api service errors
    except HttpError, error:
        print ('There was an API error : %s : %s' % (error.resp.status, error._get_reason()))

    return metrics
```

If to access Analytics with oauth2 playground is easy and working i.e. by refresh token and access token from playground itself but for Service Account Key (SAK) api to access analytics so we don't have to access tokens again and again. Code should refresh token itself using SAK api and access Analytics Data

Comment: `pip install port` installs [lightweight blogging platform](https://github.com/frnsys/port). Is it what you really need? Perhaps not.

Comment: 'Port' command is installing libffi , a lib which i need. But first i was trying to install 'port' as it was not included

Comment: I think you need MacPorts for Mac OS X: https://guide.macports.org/#installing.macports